# Sencha Touch package build returns "must be run from package folder"

Tags: android, sencha-touch

I'm very new to Sencha, and app development as a whole. I've followed the instructions here:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/getting_started
and here:
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/native_packaging-section-7
and I'm trying to use this command to package this for testing on my android device:

```
sencha package build packager.json
```

I get this result:

```
[ERR] Command must be run from a package folder
```

I feel sure that I've done everything correctly, despite the instructions being very wrong in certain places in the documentation for Sencha. It doesn't seem to matter where I try to run this command from, it doesn't work. I'm running it from the app directory.

Did I miss a step somewhere? Where is this mythical package folder where this command will run?

Comment: Generally this should be run from root of your application folder which has app.js but if that's not working please tell us which version of Sencha SDK & Sencha Cmd you are using

Comment: Thanks for the help ThinkFloyd--I've basically given up on Sencha as I just don't know enough of the basics to go on with.

Answer (score 4):

I'm getting started with Sencha and I had the same problem. The correct command is:

```
sencha app package build packager.json
```

(notice the **app** keyword missing)

Hope it helps!